# Remove white space at the end of text in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a large number of data in excel, which have whitespace in end of text.

Example :

`"Lorem ipsum "`

or

`"Lorem ipsum             "`

How can I remove the whitespace?

Result :

`"Lorem ipsum"`

UPDATE :

I look the answer and worked for normal whitespace, i did research and found my whitespace is a unicode character. So i use this method and worked.

`=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(Lorem ipsum             ,CHAR(160),CHAR(32)))`

Thanks.

Source : http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/help/remove-spaces-and-nonprinting-characters-from-text-HP010062743.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP010062581

Comment: It looks like you are looking for the [`*TRIM()` functions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/HV080557211.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the double quotes are part of the data you could use this:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(A2, LEN(A2)-1))&""""
```

Result:

[image]

If the double quotes were only for display purposes just use this:

```
=TRIM(A2)
```

Comment: Note : The first solution will only work if there is no space at the start of the data ;)

Comment: good points, but I don't think the op was after the spaces at the start of the data ;)

Answer (score 0):

In pretty much every programming languages removing the trailing spaces is done with the TRIM() function. So for your case in excel :

```
=TRIM("Lorem ipsum             ")
=TRIM("     Lorem ipsum")
=TRIM(" Lorem ipsum ")
=TRIM("Lorem ipsum")
```

Will all output the same result (without any trailing spaces):

```
Lorem ipsum
```

For more information on the trim function : http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/trim-function-HP010062581.aspx